# How to dereference entries in a hash of arrays of hashes

Tags: perl

I have a data structure that was built like so:-

```
$ICVDWKey = "($LLX $LLY) ($URX $URY)";
...
push @{$ICVDWStats{$ICVDWKey}}, {
    ICVDensity=>$Density,
    ICVLayerArea=>$LayerArea,
    ICVWindowArea=>$WindowArea
};
```

I can dereference its contents like so...

```
foreach $ICVDWKey (@AllICVDWCoords) {
    foreach (@{$ICVDWStats{$ICVDWKey}}) {
        $ICVDensity = $_->{ICVDensity};
        $ICVLayerArea = $_->{ICVLayerArea};
        $ICVWindowArea = $_->{ICVWindowArea};
        ...
     }
 }
```

...and everything is good. However, I am running into problems when another data structure is built the same way and I need to check its contents when looping through the original data structure, above. Here is an example...

```
foreach $ICVDWKey (@AllICVDWCoords) {
    foreach (@{$ICVDWStats{$ICVDWKey}}) {
        $ICVDensity = $_->{ICVDensity};
        $ICVLayerArea = $_->{ICVLayerArea};
        $ICVWindowArea = $_->{ICVWindowArea};
        ...
        if (exists ($ICC2DWStats{$ICVDWKey})) {
             $ICC2Density = $_->{ICC2Density};
             $ICC2LayerArea = $_->{ICC2LayerArea};
             $ICC2WindowArea = $_->{ICC2WindowArea};
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

I know the `if exists $ICVDWKey` matching is working properly, but I cannot cleanly dereference the contents of the ICC2DWStats hash data. What is the proper what to retrieve the `ICC2*` data when `$ICVDWKey` keys match between the two data structures? I am sure it is the `$_` in the `ICC2*` references, but I do not know what should be used instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$_` which represents a structure other than the `$ICC2DWStats` hashref which you want, you need to explicitly specify the hash and key of the actual hasn you want to extract from:

```
for $ICVDWKey (@AllICVDWCoords) {
    for (@{$ICVDWStats{$ICVDWKey}}) {
        $ICVDensity = $_->{ICVDensity};
        $ICVLayerArea = $_->{ICVLayerArea};
        $ICVWindowArea = $_->{ICVWindowArea};
        ...
        if (exists ($ICC2DWStats{$ICVDWKey})) {
             $ICC2Density = $ICC2DWStats->{$ICVDWKey}{ICC2Density};
             $ICC2LayerArea = $ICC2DWStats->{$ICVDWKey}{ICC2LayerArea};
             $ICC2WindowArea = $ICC2DWStats->{$ICVDWKey}{ICC2WindowArea};
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you should be using `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Comment: @Chris In your case the `$_` in the inner `foreach` are elements of `@{$ICVDWStats{$ICVDWKey}}`, while you want to access `@{$ICC2DWStats{$ICVDWKey})`.  In order to access "parallel" array elements you may need to switch to iterating over the index.